# Create Empty Array to put new values into IDL

Tags: loops, idl-programming-language

If I have a pre-existing array, X, and I want to extract values from X and put them into a new array, new_x, how do I do that?

I understand that I can take parts of the arrays using range functions, but I am extracting data from X using conditions written using for loops.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different ways, depending upon how large your array is. The simplest approach is to just concatenate the values into the new array. For example:

```
new_x = []
for i=0,n_elements(x)-1 do begin
  if x[i] "matches condition" then new_x = [new_x, x[i]]
endfor
```

This will work fine for small arrays but becomes very expensive and slow for large arrays, since you are always re-allocating the memory.

A better approach is to use a "flag" array, then use "WHERE" to extract the indices. For example:

```
flag = BYTARR(N_ELEMENTS(x))
for i=0,n_elements(x)-1 do begin
  if x[i] "matches condition" then flag[i] = 1
endfor
new_x = x[WHERE(flag, /NULL)]
```

The best way would be to eliminate the for loop completely, but this may not be possible. For example, let's say you just wanted X values that were within a certain data range:

```
new_x = x[WHERE(x ge 5 and x le 10, /NULL)]
```

Hopefully one of these methods will work for your problem.

Comment: It's worth noting that these methods only work for IDL >= 8.0 (specifically the `/NULL` keyword to `WHERE()` and the empty array initializer)

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your response was really helpful.

Comment: `x[where()]` should work work fine in IDL<8.0 as long as you protect from `where()` returning `-1` if it doesn't find any elements matching the conditions (or if you can safely assume that at least one element will meet conditions).